# Determine the general and singular solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, singular-solution

Determine the general and singular solutions of the equation

$$ y= xp + \frac{ap}{(1+p^2)^{1/2}} $$

where $a$ is a constant and $p=\frac{dy}{dx}$.

Since the given differential equation is in Clairaut's form, the general solution can be obtained by replacing $p$ with some $c$ (constant).

But for singular solutions, I couldn't find them as the equations are complex.

Please help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Derivation respect to $x$ of $y= xp + \dfrac{ap}{(1+p^2)^{1/2}}$ gives $p=y'=p+xp'+\cdots$ which simplify to
$$xp'+\dfrac{ap'}{\sqrt{1+p^2}^3}=0$$
now we can drop $p'$ from this, $\sqrt{1+p^2}=\sqrt[3]{-\dfrac{a}{x}}$ and from the main equation and find the result.